# An asset cannot be read from a location outside the project - Angular

Tags: angular, command-line-interface

I am having a requirement to read a file from a specific location which is outside of the angular project folder.

I tried adding

{"glob": "**/*", "input": "../../../Documents/testdata.txt", "output": "./assets/testdata.txt", "disablePathCheck": true, "allowOutsideOutDir": true}

in **assets** in **angular-cli.json** to copy the file outside the project folder inside Documents to assets folder within the project so that I can access the file using,

```
this.http.get('/src/assets/testdata.txt').subscribe((response) => {
      console.log(response);
    });
```

But I am facing ***"An asset cannot be read from a location outside the project"*** error when I try running the application.

Can someone please guide me how to resolve this issue.

**Few version related details:**
Angular CLI: 1.6.7
Node: 8.9.1
OS: linux x64
Angular: 5.2.11

Comment: You are using absolute path: `/src/....`. Maybe try `src/...` (remove leading slash). It depends on you Angular configuration, but see if this helps.

Comment: I am facing this error as soon as I try hitting ng serve and I tried src/..but it didn't work out